# Android emulator in VS code is transparent and only shows the frame

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I try to set up VS code for flutter and I am stuck with my virtual android device. When I use AndroidStudio the emulator works perfectly but in VS code I only get the frame of the virtual phone.

I already tried

- changing the graphics in the device manager to automatic, hardware, software
- in the advanced settings of the emulator I tried all different combinations of renderer and API level
- using different virtual devices (only on Android Pie though)

the funny thing is, if I diable the device frame in the Device manager it works perfectly fine in VS code as well. But I kinda like to see the device and not just the window.

Greatful for any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.